# Input voltage exceeded maximum voltage

Tags: voltage-regulator, schematic

I am using [NCP1117LPST50T3G](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/308/1/NCP1117LP_D-2316911.pdf) in my design. In the data sheet it is mentioned that maximum in put voltage to the chip is 18 V, but I accidently fed 28 V. I have attached the schematic as shown below. I have used 0.1 uF and 10 uF 25 V capacitors at the input and output.

So far there is no short between chips 3 and 2 pins to GND.

The 28 V was fed for small amount of time.

Should I replace the chip or continue?

[image]

Comment: How long was  NCP1117LPST50T3G connected to the 28V source?

Comment: *Should I replace the chip or continue?* You exceeded the maximum rating so it is anyone's guess if and what has been demaged in the chip. If the output voltage is still OK and you don't care if the circuit / components that are connected to the output are damaged then sure, you can keep using this IC. If not then you should replace it. The same thing to do is of course to replace it.

Comment: @MissMulan So you know how long this IC can withstand 28 V? That information is not in the datasheet so how do you know?

Comment: I dont know but the IC is made of transistors and Opamps and diodes.They have tolerance for conditions out of the normal for a brief amount of time

Comment: *I dont know* Then why the comment? *I dont know but the IC is made of transistors and Opamps and diodes* 1) We know 2) The error amplifier (it is not always an opamp) is made of transistors 3) what does your comment add to the discussion about 28 V?

Comment: *They have tolerance for conditions out of the normal for a brief amount of time* They do, but 1) you don't know what those conditions are so it is pointless to discuss them. 2) such a "brief amount of time" is usually extremely short, like nano-seconds.

Comment: @MissMulan It only takes microseconds to blow some elements, so, compared to human reaction times, the damage is done instantly. The IC is relatively cheap if you shop around on Ebay for example, so better safe than sorry - replace it.

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I would replace the regulator and maybe Cin (assuming it's not rated for 28V) if there were any significant consequences to the regulator subsequently failing open, short or **delivering full input voltage out the output**. Maybe Cout got exposed too.

28V is WAY more than the absolute maximum.

---

Some things get damaged instantly (eg. internal compensation capacitors) or delicate junctions. Possibly transistor beta is degraded. There are many possible failure modes and not all take significant (in human terms) time for damage to occur. The part is pennies and will likely be connected to more expensive things.

Comment: @MissMulan - Hi, Your comment was trying to give a different answer, which is not an allowed use of comments and it was flagged by other site members for that. Therefore it has been deleted. If you have a different answer, then please write an actual answer. Thanks.

Comment: Spehro - Hi, I have moved your comment into the answer to avoid losing that useful info. Obviously you can edit it, as you wish. It just became misplaced as a comment, due to subsequent events. Please let me know if I can help or any other issues with this. Thanks.